# Internal Server Error 500 al realizar petición Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web

soy nuevo en esto de la programación web y espero que me ayuden ya que me he guiado por ejemplos de peticiones AJAX y me han funcionado correctamente hasta ahora.

Realizo una petición AJAX y el resultado impreso por consola es "MantenedorUsuarioDerecho:804 POST http://localhost:8080/Prueba1/public/setQuitarDerecho 500 (Internal Server Error)"
a lo que yo no se como solucionar.

Ejecuto un onclick en un botón y rescato los datos de una fila en especifica de una tabla, con estos datos realizo la petición AJAX para luego hacer una inyección sql.

Mi código:
llamada a la función.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger m-b-0" onclick="TomarFila()" >Quitar</button>
```

La función:

```
function TomarFila(){
    var table = document.getElementById("Derechos1");
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var parametros = [];
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        row = table.rows[i];
        row.onclick = function(){
                        var cells = this.getElementsByTagName("td");
                        parametros = {_token :  token, codusu : cells[1].innerHTML, codder : cells[2].innerHTML};
                    };
    };
    QuitarDerecho(parametros);
    console.log('paso1');
}

function QuitarDerecho(datos) {
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    var parametros = datos;
    console.log('paso2');
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: '{{url('/setQuitarDerecho')}}',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //$("#spinner").show();
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            console.log('paso3');
        }
        , error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
    console.log('paso4');
}
```

Comment: Si el error es 500, es error del lado del servidor; quiere decir que está en tu backend. No se está procesando correctamente los datos. Por favor, enséñanos tu backend o tu error desde el network.

Comment: Pueden haber demasiados errores, como por ejemplo la clase ResponseFormatt, puedes utilizar Response::json($data). Es difícil saber, te doy una recomendación para saber más específicamente el error u errores, En tu página web dale click derecho al navegador y luego inspeccionar -> busca la pestaña de network -> vuelve a mandar la petición o hacer la acción -> click sobre el aviso rojo en network que sale -> click en preview. Ahí te mostrará el error más detalladamente.

Answer (score 0):

Gracais por la pronta respuesta.
Este es mi archivo de rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es del controlador.

```
    public function QuitarDerecho(request $request)
{
    // $array = json_decode($request);
    $codusu = $request->input('codusu');
    $codder = $request->input('codder');
    // $codusu = $array[0];
    // $codder = $array[1];
    // var_dump($request);

    //die;
    $respuesta= MaDerechosPDO::setQuitarDerechos($codusu, $codder);

    $respuesta = new ResponseFormatt();
    $respuesta->setCode(200)
        ->setResponse($elDato);

    return $respuesta->returnToJson();
}
```

Y esto es del PDO donde realizo la consulta como prueba pero la verdad es que necesito realizar un delete.

```
    public static function setQuitarDerecho($usuario, $derecho)
{
    $arrayReturn = null;
    // $delete = "delete re_usuader where codder = " . $codder . " and codusu = '" . $usuario . "'";
    // DB::connection('oracle_dmventas')->statement($delete);
    // DB::connection('oracle_dmventas')->statement("commit");

    $sql = "select * from re_usuader where codder = " . $codder . " and codusu = '" . $usuario . "'";
    $resultado = DB::connection('oracle')->select($sql, [
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'usuario' => $usuario
    ]);

    return $resultado;
}
```

Si necesitas algo mas me dices...

Comment: Has revisado el error.logs del apache? Todos los errores 500 aparecen allí y por lo general te dicen exactamente en cuál archivo y en qué línea se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Pueden haber demasiados errores, como por ejemplo la clase ResponseFormatt, puedes utilizar Response::json($data). Es difícil saber, te doy una recomendación para saber más específicamente el error u errores, En tu página web dale click derecho al navegador y luego inspeccionar -> busca la pestaña de network -> vuelve a mandar la petición o hacer la acción -> click sobre el aviso rojo en network que sale ->  click en preview. Ahí te mostrará el error más detalladamente.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, la verdad no supe cual era el error...
Lo que hice para solucionarlo fue borrar todo el código desde lo que era botón, funciones y rutas, luego lo volví a a escribir para ver que estuviera bien paso a paso y funciono bien...
me imagino que me faltaba algo en el código como un cierre o un ";".

Yo estoy ocupando Visual Code como editor de texto, saben de alguna extensión para la revisión de código o algún otro editor que me ayude a detectar estos errores mas fácilmente.